# How do I delete the author's message?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Trying to make a bot when you say a swear word it will remove your message and say you can't swear. How do I delete the last message sent (the one that will include the swear words)?

index.js (Only showing the part for swear words)

```
let i = 0
let msgSplittedSpace = message.content.split(" ")

while ( i < msgSplittedSpace.length ) {
    if (config.bannedWords.includes(msgSplittedSpace[i])) {
        message.reply("You cannot swear.")
        return
    }
    i++
}
```

config.json (Only swear word list & censored)

```
"bannedWords": [
    "f word",
    "s word"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `message` is a valid message object ([message class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message))

message class has a method called `.delete`
[docs on delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

so it will be
`message.delete()`

do this after you reply to them or before there is nothing wrong with where u place it

just it should be inside the `if` statement (inside the while loop) and is above the `return`

Comment: well, someone already posted a answer just 1 min before me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the message you only need to call the method [delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) of the message. Something like this:

```js
let i = 0
let msgSplittedSpace = message.content.split(" ")

while ( i < msgSplittedSpace.length ) {
    if (config.bannedWords.includes(msgSplittedSpace[i])) {
        message.reply("You cannot swear.")
        message.delete()
        return
    }
    i++
}
```